# How can I combine the $not Logical Query Operator in conjunction with other Comparison Query Operators to get a more specific yield?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

This is the result of my document after query

`players.find().fetch():`

```
{name:'john',     sessionIDz:"utFmxmRioDiZdmwGJ"},
{name:'jessica',  sessionIDz:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe"},
{name:'Liz',      sessionIDz:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe"},
{name:'Ericsson', sessionIDz:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe", Winner: 1},
{name:'Anderson', sessionIDz:"utFmxmRioDiZdmwGJ"}
```

After query:

```
players.find( { Winner: { $not: { $gte: 1 } } } ).fetch()
```

Yeilds:

```
{name:'Anderson', sessionIDz:"utFmxmRioDiZdmwGJ"},
{name:'john', sessionIDz:"utFmxmRioDiZdmwGJ"},
{name:'jessica', sessionIDz:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe"},
{name:'Liz', sessionIDz:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe"}
```

Which is fine. But now, how do I further narrow down the yield to all documents containing fields sessionIDz:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe", as illustrated below:

```
{name:'jessica', sessionIDz:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe"},
{name:'Liz', sessionIDz:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe"}
```

Is there a way I can combine the $not Logical Query Operator in conjunction with other Comparison Query Operators to achieve this yield?.

I have tried the query below, but fail to get the desired result:

```
player.find({Winner: { $not: { $gte: 1 }}}, {sessionIDz: { $eq:"FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe" } }).fetch()
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the condition within the same query object. Because the logic **NOT greater than or equal to**

```
{ "$not": { "$gte": 1 } }
```

is just the same as **LESS than**

```
{ "$lt": 1 }
```

your query may be simplified to

```
player.find({
    "Winner": { "$lt": 1 }, 
    "sessionIDz": "FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe" 
}).fetch()
```

or if you want to query where the `Winner` field does not exist, the query is

```
player.find({
    "Winner": { "$exists": false }, 
    "sessionIDz": "FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe" 
}).fetch()
```

Comment: @SirBT Any particular reason why you unaccepted this answer? Knowing so would allow me to better frame my answers in the future or address anything that you might have misunderstood.

Comment: I was under the impression that one could accept two or more answers. Am terribly sorry about this. Your answer is very well framed, no improvements required at all!

Comment: @SirBT That's alright, only one answer can be accepted

Answer (score 2):

The query json must be the first argument to the find function. You have split the query into 2 separate objects and that is why you are not getting the desired result.

Please try the following:

```
player.find( { Winner: { $not: { $gte: 1 } }, sessionIDz: "FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe" }).fetch()
```

Also, **not greater than or equal to** = **lesser than**. So the following will also achieve your results.

```
player.find( { Winner: { $lt: 1 }, sessionIDz: "FmwgXvxHZmuAwSzpe" }).fetch()
```